# Does it have a any sense or value about calling retain or release to autoreleased object?

Tags: objective-c

I have got some questions about autorelease feature.

Please advice..

Q1) Does it have a any sense or value about calling retain or release to autoreleased object?

```
ex1) 
 UIView *viewTest = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:viewTest];
```

In this condition, viewtest object will be released in future?
 Or need to add a line '[viewTest release];'?

ex2)

```
UIView *viewTest = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)] autorelease];
[viewTest release];
```

In this case, viewTest will be autorelease?

Q2) Where does autoreleased object be destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1) Does it have a any sense or value about calling retain or release to autoreleased object?

Not really, the object will get released when the autoreleasepool is drained anyway. Take a look at [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1806938&seqNum=7)

> Q2) Where does autoreleased object be destroyed?

The autoreleased object is destroyed when the `NSAutoreleasePool` is drained, or at the end of the `@autoreleasepool` construct, which basically does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`autorelease` is thought for situations, where you e.g. return an object from a method, so the caller doesn't need to release it after use.

Your ex2 should cause a problem because it does release twice.

The autoreleased objects are destryed when the pool is drained.